# Change Image on click button in table cell in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, storyboard

[image]

I want to change image on the button, when button click. That button is placed in table cell. Image is changing successfull. But when table scroll by default after every 5 cell button image also changed, while I didn't changed it. Means new cells in table, unwilling change. This cell is reusable, and created by storyboard.

How to use that button as switch button. How can I achieve this.

```
- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathWithSubview:(UIView *)subview {

        while (![subview isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell self]] && subview) {
            subview = subview.superview;
        }
        return [self.table indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)subview];
    }

    - (IBAction)btnCheckedCellPressed:(id)sender{
        NSIndexPath *myIP = [self indexPathWithSubview:(UIButton *)sender];
        MyWantsTableViewCell* cell = (MyWantsTableViewCell *)[self.table cellForRowAtIndexPath:myIP];
        if (cell.btnEdit.currentImage == [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox-active"]) {
            [cell.btnEdit setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox-deactive"]
                          forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        } else {
            [cell.btnEdit setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox-active"]
                          forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    //    [self.table beginUpdates];
    //    [self.table reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[myIP] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    //    [self.table endUpdates];

    }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    MyWantsTableViewCell *cell=nil;

    static NSString *AutoCompleteRowIdentifier = @"MyWantsTableViewCellEdit";

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:AutoCompleteRowIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[MyWantsTableViewCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:AutoCompleteRowIdentifier];
        [[AsyncImageLoader sharedLoader] cancelLoadingImagesForTarget:cell.imgProduct];
    }
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    cell.btnEdit.tag = indexPath.row;
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use simple way as I have described below, and use an object to keep the current selection, since it will go if you scroll the `UITableView`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{



   [cell.btnEdit setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox-active"]
                          forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [cell.btnEdit setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox-deactive"]
                          forState:UIControlStateSelected];

   MyClass *obj=[arr objextAtIndex:indexPath.row];

   cell.btnEdit.selected=obj.selected;


}

- (IBAction)btnCheckedCellPressed:(id)sender{
        NSIndexPath *myIP = [self indexPathWithSubview:(UIButton *)sender];
        MyWantsTableViewCell* cell = (MyWantsTableViewCell *)[self.table cellForRowAtIndexPath:myIP];

        cell.btnEdit.selected=!cell.btnEdit.selected;

        MyClass *obj=[arr objectAtIndex:myIP.row];
        obj.selected=!obj.selected;

}
```

**Sample**

Find sample for help [here](https://db.tt/Osk9VUn7)

Comment: same issue, when table scroll then after 5-6th cell is shows selected.

Comment: @GauravDS It will work, can you update your code, have you created a `NSObject class` with properties? Can you update your code, what have you implemented?

Comment: @GauravDS Added a sample in my answer. It will help you.

Comment: You need to add a property in your datasource to keep the selection safe, and that can be reuses correctly, because datasource won't change but cell does. If you see my sample, I have added a property `selected` in my datasource object class, and I am using that to save the selection, and it works.

Answer (score 2):

```
1.. Take a NSInteger variable like "selectedBtn" and initialize it with -1, in viewDidLoad(). 
2.. go to cellForRowAtIndexPath() set button.tag == indexpath.row; 
3.. Now in btnCheckedCellPressed() set that selectedBtn variable with tag value of that sender button. 
4.. Now again go to cellForRowAtIndexPath() and place a check 

if(cell.btnEdit.tag == selectedBtn)
    // set selected image on button 
else
   // set unselected Image
```